# How to get the current directory in python?

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

I'm trying to get the current directory using the OS module, like that:

```
directory=os.getcwd()
```

However, when I do this, the directory comes with \, like `'C:\Users\...'`, and I need to use directory with \\ or /.

Is that anyway to get the directory with `\\` or `/`?

Comment: Its just a string; you can manipulate it however you need to.

Comment: I already tried to replace the '\', but '\' is a special character, so I can't just do  directory.replace("\","/")

Comment: Please show what exactly you need to have instead of 'C:\Users\...'.

Comment: 'C:/Users/...', i just need to replace the \ character by the / character

Comment: You have to use two backslashes when putting a backslash in a string to represent a single backslash, so it would be `directory.replace("\\","/")`

Comment: Thanks, I've tried the link that @Passerby posted and it works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just replace the `\` with `/`. Note that the former must be escaped with another `\`, like below:

```
import os
directory = os.getcwd().replace('\\', '/')
```